# Posting To Facebook Fan Page As Admin Using PHP

Tags: facebook, api

I am using php sdk 3.0 and i want to publish streams on my fan page as admin. i use some code like below and all work fun but the streaming post are not posted  as an admin user but as fan user (the )

The login request

```
$fb = new Facebook( array(   'appId'  => $pluginParams->get('ApplicationKey'),
  'secret' => $pluginParams->get('Secret'),
  'cookie' => true
)) ;
.......
$loginUrl = $fb->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'manage_pages,offline_access,publish_stream, read_stream'));
```

The code part to send stream's

```
$body['id'] = $pluginParams->get('YourFanpageID');
$body['message']=$message;
$body['picture']=$image;
$body['caption']=$item->title;
....
$AccessToken=   $this->get_page_access_token($pluginParams->get('YourFanpageID'), $pluginParams->get('AccessToken'), $pluginParams->def('UserID',$me['id']));
......

$body = http_build_query($body);
$body = urldecode($body);

$request = array(
  'method' => 'POST',
  'relative_url' => 'feed',
  'body' => $body
);

$batch[] = $request;

$params = array(
  'access_token' => $AccessToken,  
  'batch' => json_encode($batch)
);

$result=$fb->api('/', 'POST', $params);
```

function to get access token page

```
function get_page_access_token($page_id, $access_token, $user_id) {
    $data = file_get_contents('https://graph.beta.facebook.com/'.$user_id.'/accounts?access_token='.$access_token);
    $pages = json_decode($data,true);
    foreach($pages['data'] as $page) {
      if($page['id'] == $page_id) {
        return $page['access_token']; 
      }   
   }
}
```

Can you tell pls if there are a code to add to tell the page that this is an admin post?

Posting To Facebook Fan Page As Admin Using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

In $AccessToken variable, use your(admin of the page) access_token(hardcoded) in which you have given the offline_access permission.